# ultrasonic communication

Tags: java, android, iphone, ios, signal-processing

I came across an android app called zoosh which uses ultrasonic frequencies for short range communication.

I was of the impression that android or for most of the phones for that matter can't produce ultrasonic frequencies.

Can some one tell me how this thing really works and how to implement something like this.

From my part I think that we need to produce a unique frequency for each user which can be read from the other phone's microphone. Then on the other phone we can use Discrete fourier transforms to get the max frequency in our specified range.

(By the way I want to make something like tagtile.com but by using two phones and no extra hardware)

Any help will be great.

Thanks

Comment: Apparently, most phones can produce ultrasonic frequencies. It's not that surprising -- there have been almost-ultrasonic ringtones (intended to be heard only by younger people) for years. Of course the hardware isn't designed with ultrasonic use in mind, so I imagine that it might not work on some phones.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will not be able to receive any frequency above 1/2 the sampling rate, they just fold back (aliasing). To eliminate this aliasing there is usually a filter before the A2D sampler to cut-off the frequency above 1/2 the sampling frequency.

Of course the frequencies being used are probably not actually ultrasonic, just at the upper end of the frequency capabilities and at a rather low volume and the devices being rather close together.

Using DFFT at near-ultrasonic frequencies and sampling rates close to the 2 times the frequency will give you rather wide frequency bins. Better to just use something like pulse code modulation for the data.

Per-user differentiation could be done by having a pre-amble to the data that contains the userid.

Or consider Bluetooth, GameKit offers a nice API for peer-to-peer communications over short distances. Bluetooth version 4.0 offers very fast connections albeit it is only available on the newest devices.

Note: The term "ultrasonic" applied to sound refers to anything above the frequencies of audible sound, and nominally includes anything over 20,000 Hz.

Answer (score 0):

If you've got 2 phones - go get a pair of free apps - anything that lets you produce high-frequency sounds, and anything that shows you an "audio scope" from the mic.

Using these - you can clearly visualize that it's possible to send data from one device which shows up on the other, but which cannot be heard by humans!  Of course... there's a bunch of things that do this, as you noticed, but it's always fun to watch it yourself :-)

Zoosh sell an SDK - seems like you found that already though?